# React Table Sorting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have started to learn React. Im not able to sort the react table. Im Following material UI pagination, sorting and Filtering, when i do console log(a[order] > b[order])  or console log(a[order] < b[order]) it throws undefined

Below is my code.

```
function stableSort(array, comparator) {
    const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index]);
    //console.log(stabilizedThis);
    stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
      const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
      if (order != 0) return order;
      //console.log(order);
      return a[1] - b[1];
    });

    return stabilizedThis.map((el) => el[0]);
  }

  function getComparator(order, orderBy) {
    //console.log(order, orderBy);
    if (order === 'desc') {
      return (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
    } else {
      return (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
    }

  }

  function descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy) {
    // console.log(b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]);
    //console.log(a.orderBy);
    if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  const tablePagingAndSorting = () => {
    return stableSort(customers, getComparator(order, orderBy)).slice(page * rowsPerPage, (page + 1) * rowsPerPage);
  };


  const headCells = [
    { id: 1, text: '#' },
    { id: 2, text: 'Name' },
    { id: 3, text: 'Phone' },
    { id: 4, text: 'Email' },
    { id: 5, text: 'Action' },
  ];

  const handleSortRequest = (cellId) => {
    const isAsc = orderBy == cellId && order == 'asc';
    setOrder(isAsc ? 'desc' : 'asc');
    setOrderBy(cellId);
  };
```

Table :

```
  {headCells.map((headCell, index) => {
              return (
                <TableCell key={headCell.id} align='center'>
                  <TableSortLabel active={orderBy == headCell.id} direction={orderBy == headCell.id ? order : 'asc'} onClick={() => handleSortRequest(headCell.id)}>
                    {headCell.text}
                  </TableSortLabel>
                </TableCell>
              );
            })}
```